# Delegate movement in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain to me what this is asking in the //TBD and perhaps give me some examples of how this would work? I understand some if it a bit but still am having trouble with anything I try.

```
  namespace DelgateKeypress
 {
class Program
{
    private static int x=20;
    private static int y=20;

    //TBD: You will need to define a data structure to store the association 
    //between the KeyPress and the Action the key should perform


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //TBD: Set up your control scheme here. It should look something like this:
        //   myControls.Add(ConsoleKey.W, Up)
        //   myControls.Add(ConsoleKey.S, Down)
        //or you can ask the user which keys they want to use
        //etc





        while (true)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write("O");

            var key = Console.ReadKey(true);


            int oldX = x;
            int oldY = y;


            //TBD: Replace the following 4 lines by looking up the key press in the data structure
            //and then performing the correct action
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.W) Up();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.S) Down();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.A) Left();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.D) Right();

            Console.SetCursorPosition(oldX, oldY);
            Console.Write(".");


        }
    }

    private static void Right()
    {
        x++;
    }

    private static void Left()
    {
        x--;
    }

    private static void Down()
    {
        y++;
    }

    private static void Up()
    {
        y--;
    }
}
```

}

I kind of understand it a bit but I am having trouble trying to get the user to be able to input which value they would like to add for each of the key movements for up, down, left and right. I don't have to have that happen it could just be W,S,A,D for those movements but I am at a loss here so any help would be fantastic guys.

Comment: Do a search for the documentation on `Dictionary<K, V>`. That will help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework for a class? If so, you should definitely follow up with your teacher to have them explain in more detail why you were given this assignment, how you were expected to complete it, and to ensure that you've gotten from the exercise what your teacher wanted you to. In the meantime…

It seems to me that based on the sample syntax provided in the comments (e.g. `myControls.Add(ConsoleKey.W, Up)`), that the author of those comments is expecting you to declare a `Dictionary<ConsoleKey, Action>`, populate it, and then use it as keys are pressed.

The declaration would look like this:

```
static Dictionary<ConsoleKey, Action> myControls;
```

The initialization would look like this:

```
myControls = new Dictionary<ConsoleKey, Action>
{
    { ConsoleKey.W, Up },
    { ConsoleKey.S, Down },
    { ConsoleKey.A, Left },
    { ConsoleKey.D, Right },
};
```

And you would use it like this:

```
myControls[key.Key]();
```

Or if it possible for a key value that is not present in the data structure (as seems likely in your example):

```
Action action;

if (myControls.TryGetValue(key.Key, out action))
{
    action();
}
```